# Deserialize XML with C# from URL

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm pulling an XML-Sitemap from a website to parse it.

The easyest way would be to deserialize it into on objet.

I get throw the error "Error in XML-Document" on the last line in my example-code. Does anybody know why. There aren't any more details in the error-message.

My Code so far:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("urlset")]
public class Urlset
{
    public B5_Url[] urls;
}
[XmlType("url")]
public class B5_Url
{
    [XmlElement("loc")]
    public string loc;
    [XmlElement("lastmod")]
    public string lastmod;
    [XmlElement("changefreq")]
    public string changefreq;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "http://www.myurl.de/sitemap.xml";

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Urlset));

        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        string data = Encoding.Default.GetString(client.DownloadData(url));

        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));

        Urlset reply = (Urlset)ser.Deserialize(stream);  
    }
}
```

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9             http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<url>
  <loc>http://www.myurl.de/</loc>
  <lastmod>2012-06-25T17:10:30+00:00</lastmod>
  <changefreq>always</changefreq>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Usually you should get an inner-exception when deserialization fails.

Comment: I bet you don't get a message "Error in XML-Document". I bet you get a whole bunch of info about a specific Exception. You should add it to your question.

Comment: If you can confirm the correct state of `<urlset>` I'll run it through my test app again.

Answer (score 4):

You should do what @vitalygolub is suggesting. Also, you will still get an error because of Namespace set in the  root element. To fix it:

```
[XmlRoot("urlset", Namespace="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")]
public class Urlset
{
    [XmlElement("url")]
    public B5_Url[] urlset;
}

public class B5_Url
{
    [XmlElement("loc")]
    public string loc;
    [XmlElement("lastmod")]
    public string lastmod;
    [XmlElement("changefreq")]
    public string changefreq;
}
```

I tested this code and it works with your input.

Answer (score 1):

If that is your XML, you're missing a closing `</url>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9             http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<url>
  <loc>http://www.myurl.de/</loc>
  <lastmod>2012-06-25T17:10:30+00:00</lastmod>
  <changefreq>always</changefreq>
</url>
</urlset>
```

I got the error `<urlset xmlns='http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'> was not expected.`

Changing:

`<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9             http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">`

To

`<urlset>`

Made it not error.

This is my working linqpad example

```
[Serializable, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("urlset")]
public class Urlset
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("url")]
    public B5_Url[] urls;
}
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType("url")]
public class B5_Url
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("loc")]
    public string loc;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("lastmod")]
    public string lastmod;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("changefreq")]
    public string changefreq;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><urlset><url><loc>http://www.myurl.de/</loc><lastmod>2012-06-25T17:10:30+00:00</lastmod><changefreq>always</changefreq></url></urlset>";

        var ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Urlset));

        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));

        Urlset reply = (Urlset)ser.Deserialize(stream);  
        reply.Dump();
    }
}
```

The other change I had to make was the `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("url")]` attribute on the `B5_Url[]` array in `UrlSet`

Comment: Sadly it's not that easy. I just forgot the closing URL-Tag in my example. Thank you

Comment: @B5-NDDT is the namespace on your sample XML correct? I get an error on that too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the following

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("urlset")]
public class Urlset
{
    [XmlElement("url")]
    public B5_Url[] urls;
}
```

Which will serialize every element in a collection directly into your root-element instead of an `urls`-element.

EDIT: You can however omit the `XmlType`-attribute from `B5_Url`.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because your classes will be serialized as this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <urls>
    <url>
      <loc>http://www.myurl.de/</loc>
      <lastmod>2012-06-25T17:10:30+00:00</lastmod>
      <changefreq>always</changefreq>
    </url>
  </urls>
</urlset>
```

Try change like this

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("urlset")]
    public class Urlset
    {
        [XmlElement("urlset") ]  //should be here
        public B5_Url[] urls;
    }
    [XmlType("url")]
    public class B5_Url
    {
        [XmlElement("loc")]
        public string loc;
        [XmlElement("lastmod")]
        public string lastmod;
        [XmlElement("changefreq")]
        public string changefreq;
    }
```